# postgres equivalent approach to pandas pivot, then unstack?

Tags: pandas, postgresql, crosstab

I'm trying to learn to use postgres / sql  as an alternative to pandas.

I have a flat table that I pivot and then unstack to get the data into my required format.

Example table

```
          Date   ID  Period Metric  Value
0   2021-01-01  id1       1      A      1
1   2021-01-01  id1       2      A      3
2   2021-01-01  id1       1      B      6
3   2021-01-01  id1       2      B      1
4   2021-01-01  id2       1      A     10
5   2021-01-01  id2       2      A      6
6   2021-01-01  id2       1      B      5
7   2021-01-01  id2       2      B      4
8   2021-01-02  id1       1      A      8
9   2021-01-02  id1       2      A      3
10  2021-01-02  id1       1      B      1
11  2021-01-02  id1       2      B      4
12  2021-01-02  id2       1      A      3
13  2021-01-02  id2       2      A      6
14  2021-01-02  id2       1      B      4
15  2021-01-02  id2       2      B      8
```

Current pandas approach:

```py
d = {'Date': {0: '2021-01-01', 1: '2021-01-01', 2: '2021-01-01', 3: '2021-01-01', 4: '2021-01-01', 5: '2021-01-01', 6: '2021-01-01', 7: '2021-01-01', 8: '2021-01-02', 9: '2021-01-02', 10: '2021-01-02', 11: '2021-01-02', 12: '2021-01-02', 13: '2021-01-02', 14: '2021-01-02', 15: '2021-01-02'}, 'ID': {0: 'id1', 1: 'id1', 2: 'id1', 3: 'id1', 4: 'id2', 5: 'id2', 6: 'id2', 7: 'id2', 8: 'id1', 9: 'id1', 10: 'id1', 11: 'id1', 12: 'id2', 13: 'id2', 14: 'id2', 15: 'id2'}, 'Period': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 1, 7: 2, 8: 1, 9: 2, 10: 1, 11: 2, 12: 1, 13: 2, 14: 1, 15: 2}, 'Metric': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'B', 4: 'A', 5: 'A', 6: 'B', 7: 'B', 8: 'A', 9: 'A', 10: 'B', 11: 'B', 12: 'A', 13: 'A', 14: 'B', 15: 'B'}, 'Value': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 6, 3: 1, 4: 10, 5: 6, 6: 5, 7: 4, 8: 8, 9: 3, 10: 1, 11: 4, 12: 3, 13: 6, 14: 4, 15: 8}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df = df.pivot(index=["Date", "ID", "Period"], columns="Metric", values="Value")
df_conv = df.unstack()
df_conv.columns = [f'{x}-{y}' for x, y in df_conv.columns]
print(df_conv)
```

Giving output in required format:

```
                A-1  A-2  B-1  B-2
Date       ID                     
2021-01-01 id1    1    3    6    1
           id2   10    6    5    4
2021-01-02 id1    8    3    1    4
           id2    3    6    4    8
```

How would I perform the equivalent operation using postgres - crosstab?

Dummy data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl (
   Date   timestamp,
   ID    text,
   Period        integer,
   Metric text,
   Value double precision
);

INSERT INTO tbl VALUES 
  ('2021-01-01', 'id1', 1, 'A', 1),
    ('2021-01-01', 'id1', 2, 'A', 3),
      ('2021-01-01', 'id1', 1, 'B', 6),
        ('2021-01-01', 'id1', 2, 'B', 1),
  ('2021-01-01', 'id2', 1, 'A', 10),
    ('2021-01-01', 'id2', 2, 'A', 6),
      ('2021-01-01', 'id2', 1, 'B', 5),
        ('2021-01-01', 'id2', 2, 'B', 4),        
  ('2021-01-02', 'id1', 1, 'A', 8),
    ('2021-01-02', 'id1', 2, 'A', 3),
      ('2021-01-02', 'id1', 1, 'B', 1),
        ('2021-01-02', 'id1', 2, 'B', 4),        
  ('2021-01-02', 'id2', 1, 'A', 3),
    ('2021-01-02', 'id2', 2, 'A', 6),
      ('2021-01-02', 'id2', 1, 'B', 4),
        ('2021-01-02', 'id2', 2, 'B', 8)        
        ;
```

Comment: If there are only (exactly) two periods, the simplest is a self-join.

Comment: There could be more periods in reality, I was trying to keep simple for purposes of example